# open solaris dns issue

Tags: domain-name-system, opensolaris

I have just installed Open Solaris on a sunfire x4170. dig and nslookup seem to work and i can open web pages through firefox if I use the ip address, but I can't seem to open pages in firefox i.e. google.com or ping google.com ( I'm just using google.com as an example i have tried several different sites)

Here is output from dig command:

```
~# dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1 <<>> google.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 1526
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             209     IN      A       74.125.67.100
google.com.             209     IN      A       74.125.127.100
google.com.             209     IN      A       74.125.45.100

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.             131266  IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
google.com.             131266  IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
google.com.             131266  IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
google.com.             131266  IN      NS      ns1.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.google.com.         343110  IN      A       216.239.32.10
ns2.google.com.         343110  IN      A       216.239.34.10
ns3.google.com.         338914  IN      A       216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.         333491  IN      A       216.239.38.10

;; Query time: 12 msec
;; SERVER: 203.96.152.4#53(203.96.152.4)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep  4 09:26:12 2009
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 212
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does /etc/nsswitch.conf look like? Specifically, does the `hosts` entry include `dns`, e.g.

```
hosts:      files dns
```

If it doesn't *and* you're just using DNS for host name resolution it should be sufficient to copy /etc/nsswitch.dns over /etc/nsswitch.conf. Other files have example configurations for other name resolution and authentication methods, e.g. nsswitch.ldap.